# CSS to display table with one row per cell on narrow screens

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have HTML that looks a bit like this

```html
<html><body><table>
  <thead><tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>E</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1A</td><td>1B</td><td>1C</td><td>1D</td><td>1E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2A</td><td>2B</td><td>2C</td><td>2D</td><td>2E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3A</td><td>3B</td><td>3C</td><td>3D</td><td>3E</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table></body></html>
```

Each row represents an object, and the columns are its properties.  The cell values are rather longer in reality – sometimes even 20–30 characters long.  It renders fine on most devices, but can be problematic on smaller phones.  I know I can suppress certain columns on narrow devices, but that doesn’t feel right in this particular instance.  Currently I have `x-overflow: scroll` on the table, but I would prefer to have some CSS that causes the table to render more like this on narrow devices:

```
A: 1A
B: 1B
C: 1C
D: 1D
E: 1E
-----
A: 2A
B: 2B
C: 2C
D: 2D
E: 2E
-----
(etc)
```

I understand how to test for device width, so for the purpose of this question, let’s assume I want to do this unconditionally.  Changing the HTML markup a bit is okay, e.g. to add extra classes or attributes, though I’d like to keep it using a `<table>` element with one `<tr>` per logical row.  This is for backwards compatibility as I know quite a few users scrape the site (despite the existence of a much cleaner API).  Due to internal politics, I’d prefer to avoid a solution that requires Javascript, if possible (and in any case, I know how to write a JS solution if need be).

I can get part way there with this, but I’m not sure how to start with the field names which are just hardcoded to ‘X’ here:

```css
  thead { display: none; }
  table, tr, td { display: block; }
  tr + tr { border-top: thin solid black; }
  td::before { content: "X:"; display: inline-block; width: 2em; }
```

I’ve seen lots of sites do this sort of thing, but at the moment I’m struggling to find one that does it in CSS.  It seems like it should be a frequently asked question, but I’m struggling to know what terms to search for, so may be missing some good explanations, here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Might use e.g. `data-col` attributes on `<td>` elements and refer them in CSS `content` on `:before`

```css
thead {
  display: none;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  display: block;
}

tr+tr {
  border-top: thin solid black;
}

td::before {
  content: attr(data-col)':';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-col="A">1A</td>
      <td data-col="B">1B</td>
      <td data-col="C">1C</td>
      <td data-col="D">1D</td>
      <td data-col="E">1E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-col="A">2A</td>
      <td data-col="B">2B</td>
      <td data-col="C">2C</td>
      <td data-col="D">2D</td>
      <td data-col="E">2E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-col="A">3A</td>
      <td data-col="B">3B</td>
      <td data-col="C">3C</td>
      <td data-col="D">3D</td>
      <td data-col="E">3E</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another approach using CSS variables to store cols, less repetitive, so may save you some bytes on longer tables:

```css
thead {
  display: none;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  display: block;
}

tr+tr {
  border-top: thin solid black;
}

td:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
}

td:nth-child(1):before {
  content: var(--col1)':';
}

td:nth-child(2):before {
  content: var(--col2)':';
}

td:nth-child(3):before {
  content: var(--col3)':';
}

td:nth-child(4):before {
  content: var(--col4)':';
}

td:nth-child(5):before {
  content: var(--col5)':';
}
```

```html
<table style="--col1:'A'; --col2:'B'; --col3:'C'; --col4:'D'; --col5:'E'">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1A</td>
      <td>1B</td>
      <td>1C</td>
      <td>1D</td>
      <td>1E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2A</td>
      <td>2B</td>
      <td>2C</td>
      <td>2D</td>
      <td>2E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3A</td>
      <td>3B</td>
      <td>3C</td>
      <td>3D</td>
      <td>3E</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple once you know how!  Thanks.  I don’t suppose it’s possible to read the attribute from a different element (the corresponding `<th>`) to avoid the data attribute repetition, is it?  Not a big problem if not.

Comment: @RichardSmith, you cannot read attributes from a different element.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I've updated my answer with a less repetitive approach.

Comment: – Thanks.  That's very ingenious.